# Ocultar uma pergunta ao selecionar outra no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Bom dia, estou finalizando um website aqui para empresa onde trabalho, e falta apenas um detalhe para concluí-lo, porém como meu conhecimento em javascript é um pouco limitado, gostaria de uma ajudinha... A minha dúvida é a seguinte, encontrei na internet um FAQ dinâmico feito com um acordion em javascript que funciona da seguinte forma:

Código em Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var MqM= 768,
        MqL = 1024;

    var faqsSections = $('.cd-faq-group'),
        faqTrigger = $('.cd-faq-trigger'),
        faqsContainer = $('.cd-faq-items'),
        faqsCategoriesContainer = $('.cd-faq-categories'),
        faqsCategories = faqsCategoriesContainer.find('a'),
        closeFaqsContainer = $('.cd-close-panel');

    //select a faq section 
    faqsCategories.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedHref = $(this).attr('href'),
            target= $(selectedHref);
        if( $(window).width() < MqM) {
            faqsContainer.scrollTop(0).addClass('slide-in').children('ul').removeClass('selected').end().children(selectedHref).addClass('selected');
            closeFaqsContainer.addClass('move-left');
            $('body').addClass('cd-overlay');
        } else {
            $('body,html').animate({ 'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 130}, 200); 
        }
    });

    //Fecha a o faq painel
    $('body').bind('click touchstart', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('body.cd-overlay') || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-panel')) { 
            closePanel(event);
        }
    });
    faqsContainer.on('swiperight', function(event){
        closePanel(event);
    });

    //Mostra o conteúdo clicado
    faqTrigger.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.cd-faq-content').slideToggle(200).end().parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
    });

    //Atualiza a barra da categoria enquanto rolava
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if ( $(window).width() > MqL ) {
            (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? updateCategory() : window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCategory); 
        }
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if($(window).width() <= MqL) {
            faqsCategoriesContainer.removeClass('is-fixed').css({
                '-moz-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                'transform': 'translateY(0)',
            });
        }   
        if( faqsCategoriesContainer.hasClass('is-fixed') ) {
            faqsCategoriesContainer.css({
                'left': faqsContainer.offset().left,
            });
        }
    });

    function closePanel(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        faqsContainer.removeClass('slide-in').find('li').show();
        closeFaqsContainer.removeClass('move-left');
        $('body').removeClass('cd-overlay');
    }

    function updateCategory(){
        updateCategoryPosition();
        updateSelectedCategory();
    }

    function updateCategoryPosition() {
        var top = $('.cd-faq').offset().top,
            height = jQuery('.cd-faq').height() - jQuery('.cd-faq-categories').height(),
            margin = 20;
        if( top - margin <= $(window).scrollTop() && top - margin + height > $(window).scrollTop() ) {
            var leftValue = faqsCategoriesContainer.offset().left,
                widthValue = faqsCategoriesContainer.width();
            faqsCategoriesContainer.addClass('is-fixed').css({
                'left': leftValue,
                'top': margin,
                '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                'transform': 'translateZ(0)',
            });
        } else if( top - margin + height <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            var delta = top - margin + height - $(window).scrollTop();
            faqsCategoriesContainer.css({
                '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                'transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
            });
        } else { 
            faqsCategoriesContainer.removeClass('is-fixed').css({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 0,
            });
        }
    }

    function updateSelectedCategory() {
        faqsSections.each(function(){
            var actual = $(this),
                margin = parseInt($('.cd-faq-title').eq(1).css('marginTop').replace('px', '')),
                activeCategory = $('.cd-faq-categories a[href="#'+actual.attr('id')+'"]'),
                topSection = (activeCategory.parent('li').is(':first-child')) ? 0 : Math.round(actual.offset().top);

            if ( ( topSection - 20 <= $(window).scrollTop() ) && ( Math.round(actual.offset().top) + actual.height() + margin - 20 > $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
                activeCategory.addClass('selected');
            }else {
                activeCategory.removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

O evento que eu precisava era que ao clicar numa pergunta, a outra automaticamente fechasse...

Alguém pode esclarecer minha dúvida?

Um grande abraço.

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML para termos um exemplo a funcionar? Assim de repente acho que basta juntar `$('.content-visible').slideToggle(200);` dentro de `faqTrigger.on('click', function(event){`, depois do `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: o que seria o seu "fechasse"? ficou meio vago isso mas da uma olhada neste [site](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) sempre tento por lá antes de perguntar aqui.

Comment: Não daria para utilizar talvez o accordion do Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Answer (score 2):

da uma olhada neste site http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show tem bons exemplos. Talvez isto te ajude

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```